# Custom cell is registered and used in TableView controller but in app is default cell

Tags: uitableview, uikit, custom-cell

I want to use my custom cell in UITableViewController which is used in TableViewController. I register custom cell and used it in cellForRowAt method. Cell is "created" in storyboard. All classes for controllers are setted and identifiers as well, for custom cell is also selected class and identifier. But when I launch my app it shows default empty cells. Here is my code:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let beersList = BeersListModuleBuilder.createBeersListView()
        let beersListNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: beersList)
        beersListNavController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "All beers", image: nil, tag: 1)
        
        let favoriteBeersList = UIViewController()
        let favoriteBeersListNavController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: favoriteBeersList)
        favoriteBeersListNavController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Favorites", image: nil, tag: 2)
        self.viewControllers = [beersListNavController, favoriteBeersListNavController]
    }
}

class BeersListTableViewController: UITableViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.register(BeerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BeerCell")
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BeerCell", for: indexPath) as! BeerCell
        cell.beerName?.text = "beer.name"
        cell.beerABV?.text = "beer.abv"
        cell.addToFavoritesButton?.setImage(UIImage(systemName:"star"), for: .normal)
        return cell
    }
}

class BeerCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var beerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var beerABV: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var addToFavoritesButton: UIButton!
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

GitHub repo: https://github.com/IgorShevtshenko/BeerList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line:

```
self.tableView.register(BeerCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "BeerCell")
```

When you use prototype cells in a storyboard scene, the storyboard registers the class against the reuse identifier for you. You need to register your cell only if you are using custom class or nib.

Comment: may be I missunderstood you, but I m using custom class (BeerCell) or ?

Comment: By custom class I meant the case when your cell is defined entirely in code :) 

So, there are 3 options:
1. Cell is created in code - register it with `func register(AnyClass?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)` 

2. Cell is created using nib  - register with `func register(UINib?, forCellReuseIdentifier: String)`

3. Prototype cell is created in storyboard - no need to register it as stated in my answer.

Comment: So if I remove this line of code i will get error from 1 of my previous questions : unable to dequeue a cell with identifier BeerCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a protoype cell in storyboard”

Comment: Have you double checked that your cell identifier in storyboard doesn't contain trailing space or anything else (having Cyrillic symbol(s) in `BeerCell` for example could cause this issue)?

Comment: Yes, checked (copy-pasted from code to storyboard) and nothing changed

Comment: My suggestion is that problem not in cell itself, but may be in tabbar controller or something else because when i create same cell with same steps but with single tableview controller it works fine

Comment: I added link to GitHub repo

Comment: So, the issue is: you actually create 2 instances of `BeersListTableViewController`: one is instantiated from Storyboard and another one is initialized in your `TabBarController` from `BeersListModuleBuilder`. First one doesn't need cell registration and the second one does.
So, first thing you need to do is to get rid of VCs initialization in TabBarController's `viewDidLoad` (or vice versa: move everything to code).

Comment: Thanks that finally help me!!